# Django - How to use getattr for Dynamic Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django - How to use getattr for Dynamic Model.

I cannot make this work.

```
_tipo = getattr(Model(), request.GET.get('modelName'))('objects')
        print(_tipo.all())
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: The most recent Dharanidhar

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this [get_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) method to obtain a model. Then you can use `getattr` method for `objects`.

```
from django.apps import apps
Model = apps.get_model('app_label', request.GET.get('modelName'))
_tipo = getattr(Model, 'objects')
print(_tipo.all())
```